# Emulating CSS3 border-radius and box-shadow in IE7/8

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I'm working on HTML for a small web application; the design calls for a content area with rounded corners and a drop shadow. I've been able to produce this with CSS3, and it works flawlessly on Firefox and Chrome:

[image: CSS3 Version]

However, Internet Explorer 7 and 8 (not supporting CSS3) is a different story:

[image: Internet Explorer Version]

Is there an easy, lightweight JavaScript solution that would allow me to either 1) use IE-specific features to achieve this, or 2) modify the DOM (programmatically) in such a way that adds custom images around the content area to emulate the effect?

Comment: in my opinion there is no good solution to this problem beside doing it with images. The JS rounded corners are placing elements in your corners with the background image/color to create this effect in IE. i think its not a proper solution. I would use a solution with images, or wait for IE9 :P PS: i like this design.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is my method, I use the conditionals to target CSS files to IE browsers.

Say you have your *div* with the id #page_container. In your regular master.css or css3.css file, you would give it your width, height, rounded corners and drop shadow with styles.

Now, when IE hits your page, it will pull in the condition css you had set up. For that same div#page_container, you may alter the width a bit, height, maybe some padding, then give it a background-image to make it look like the drop shadow, rounded-corner version.

So your *head* will have this:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="master.css" />
<!--[if lte IE 8]> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" /> <![endif]-->
</head>
```

In the master.css file, you would have this definition for your main div:

```
div#page_container {
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  drop-shadow: whatever...
  rounded-corner: whatever...
}
```

Now, in your ie.css file, and because it is referenced in your  second, the definition will *cascade* down so you can alter it a bit:

```
div#page_container {
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px; /* this is key */
  background: #ccc url(/path/to/image.file) no-repeat top left;
}
```

Add just enough extra padding so the drop shadows fit in with your background-image. Because it cascades down, it will overwrite the original 10px padding you had, expanding the box model to fit in your extra shadow graphics.

Couple benefits to this method include:

- Only IE will see this definition and the call to the image. If this is a high volume app, that will save on bandwidth and any delays associated with the call.
- Likewise, because you didn't hard code in the rounded corner graphics that every browser would see, your Firefox and Safari users won't need hit the server with extra image calls.
- No need to add in yet another javascript plug-in that checks for IE, creates new markup, time, etc...

Comment: I've chosen to go with this solution as it seems the cleanest. I'll be incorporating a touch of IE-only JavaScript to assist with some of the DOM-level modifications to make this a little cleaner as well.

Comment: @Adam Maras - wise choice. I've used different plugins on different projects and always came to problems because the plugin affected some other of my elements. Now for last year I used similar aproach to this and I can say that it pays off on huge projects. I would go with a plugin for a simple < 5 pages site.

Comment: This may have been the way the author went, but I think some of the plugins (particularly pie.htc) have come a long way and deserve an additional look.  This method wastes development time cutting images for browsers that are loosing market-share, rather than including a solution (like pie.htc) that works in IE6-8 with minimal fuss and trouble.  I resisted the plugins for a long time myself, but they have become an invaluable tool in the arsenal now.

Answer (score 30):

Check out this post: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/

It covers specifically rounded corners and box shadow for CSS3 in IE7/8.

Comment: +1 looks like a nice solution to me. I have tested them in IE6, 7 and 8, and they are pretty slow, but they work. (specially the rounded corners took long for just 4 corners, i wonder how it covers a entire page)

Comment: The question is whether these solutions will interact to give me both rounded corners *and* drop shadows. I will investigate.

Comment: you can combine the two techniques. The problem with this one is that your server mus be able to load HTC files.

Comment: The HTC files are a bit of pain but once you've got everything organized, it works like a charm.

Comment: I think a VML solution is probably the way to go. Looking at the code in the htc file, it could be minified and sped up a little.

Comment: The real good solution would be this, adding images will increase your server requests, slow down your page load time, etc.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it summarized the pertinent techniques from that URL.

Answer (score 24):

First of all I like to mention that there is no perfect solution for this until IE9, where the CSS border-radius is gonna be implemented.

Here are the different solutions you have until then:

You could use one of many JS scripts that simulates rounded corners. But none of them implement the shadow properly. Here is the list of the scripts i tried and my conclusions.
All of this scripts have something in common, they are placing additional elements in your HTML to give you the illusion of rounded corners.

- [**DD Roundies**](http://dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/#): This script is very lightweight an works pretty well. It works without any framework and plays nice with jQuery & Prototype (i assume its working well with the others to, but i can't tell for sure). It uses the CSS3 proprieties on browsers who support CSS3. And uses the same hack as all the others for IE. The antialiazing on this one works very good.
  *edit* i have to correct my self here. This one works with a HTC File. It does not placing additional elements in your HTML.
- **[Curvy Corners](http://www.curvycorners.net/) and the [jQuery
  Plugin Curvy Corners](http://blue-anvil.com/jquerycurvycorners/test.html):** I like this one to. The antialiazing is working very good to. And it plays nice with background images. But it does not play nice with CSS3 shadows. It does not check if your Browser support CSS3 and always uses the ugly solution of adding elements to your dom.
- **[Nifty Corners](http://www.html.it/articoli/niftycube/index.html) & [jquery
  Corner](http://www.methvin.com/jquery/jq-corner-demo.html):** Both have a bad antialiazing and the corners look very edgy. jQuery corners has trouble to handle background images.

Here is the reason why none of them is a proper solution in my opinion:

[curvy corners dom messing screenshot http://meodai.ch/stackoverflow/curvy.png](http://meodai.ch/stackoverflow/curvy.png)
curvy dom mess

[nifty dom mess http://meodai.ch/stackoverflow/nifty.png](http://meodai.ch/stackoverflow/nifty.png)
nifty dom mess

There are a few other but i think they are not mentionable at this place.

As you can see they are adding a lot of elements to your dom. This can cause trouble if you want to add rounded corners to a huge amount of elements. It can make some older browser / computers crash. For the shadows its pretty much the same problem. There is a jQuery plugin that handles shadows on boxes and fonts:
http://dropshadow.webvex.limebits.com/

*My conclusion*: If i am doing a small budget job, IE users just have edges and no shadows. If the client has some money to spend, so i am doing it with CSS only and i make images for every corner. If they absolutely have to be there but there is no time or no money to do it, i use one of the mentioned JS Scripts DD_roundies with preference. Now its up to you.

PS: IE users are used to ugly interfaces, they don't gonna see that the corners and shadows are missing anyway :P

Comment: +1 for the 'PS' plus I think CSS should be allowed graceful degradation if the newer/cooler features aren't present. I also think IE users deserve to suffer a little, but that's just me being vindictive... =)

Comment: +1 for the PS too. Couldn't agree more. IE is the bane of all web developers.

Answer (score 22):

It was just released and it's in beta but check it out: http://css3pie.com/

Comment: CSS3 PIE is amazing!. It's in beta2 stage!

Comment: This is amazing! Haven't checked ie7 yet, but it sure looks exactly like it should in ie8.

Answer (score 8):

I've started using the .htc script found here:
[CSS3 support for Internet Explorer 6, 7, and 8](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/)

It's the simplest implementation of CSS3 for IE6+ that I've seen.

```
.box {
  -moz-border-radius: 15px; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px; /* Safari and Chrome */
  border-radius: 15px; /* Opera 10.5+, future browsers, and now also Internet Explorer 6+ using IE-CSS3 */

  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #000; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #000; /* Safari and Chrome */
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #000; /* Opera 10.5+, future browsers and IE6+ using IE-CSS3 */

  behavior: url(ie-css3.htc); /* This lets IE know to call the script on all elements which get the 'box' class */
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I have been using CSS3PIE, which is pretty easy to implement, just add a behavior:url(pie.htc); to the css tag and you're good to go.. does it all for you, also includes support for border-image, gradients, box-shadow, rgba and a few others... the source is at: http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 4):

for drop-shadow in IE use:

```
.shadow {
  background-color: #fff;
  zoom: 1;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#969696', Direction=135, Strength=3);
}
```

for round corners use [DD_roundies](http://dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/#download) as mentioned below, just **9Kb** is a good compromise for have round corner in a second! ;-)

of course for `programmatically IE-specific features` use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

To allow graceful degradation I bet you should use this script called CssUserAgent from http://www.cssuseragent.org/

Answer (score 2):

[Nifty Corners Cube](http://www.html.it/articoli/niftycube/index.html) produces nice results and is supposed to be downwards compatible all the way to IE5.5.

Answer (score 1):

There is a jquery plugin that modifies the DOM to produce rounded corners. Check it out here:

http://blue-anvil.com/jquerycurvycorners/test.html

There example page rendered for me in IE, Chrome and FF. Using Firebug you can see that the plugin introduces a bunch of 1px by 1px divs that create the effect.