# CSS browser safe way to apply a radius border?

Tags: html, css

I want to apply a 3px top left & top right radius border.

How can I do this across all browsers (e.g. IE, WebKit, Mozilla)?

And if the browser doesn't support the border-radius attribute, just default to no radius (square corner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[border-radius.com](http://www.border-radius.com/) is great for this:

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
border-top-left-radius: 3px;
border-top-right-radius: 3px;
```

Comment: check out the link i have posted for msie.

Comment: meo's link is good. Jump to this page: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/ as well. There is no straightforward CSS solution for MSIE. :-(

Answer (score 3):

If IE ever supports any standards ill eat my hat.

This is the best you can hope for:

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
border-top-left-radius: 3px;
border-top-right-radius: 3px;
```

Edit: my bad, missed the "top left and right only" part, corrected the codez

Comment: IE is the first one in his list, but the only one not covered by your example :P Check the link i have posted

Comment: True, but the OP also said "And if the browser doesn't support the border-radius attribute, just default to no radius" which is what will happen. So the answer is correct.

Comment: To elaborate, @sarah, this is exactly what you want. IE does not support rounded corners, so it will simply show square ones. WebKit (Safari) and Moz (Firefox et al) do support rounded corners, via the browser-specific CSS (the rules with the prefix). The simple `border-radius` is used for future-proofing.

Comment: This applies a border radius to the entire element, not just the topleft & topright

Comment: you can throw in some DD_[roundies](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/) for some IE round corners w/o images.

Answer (score 1):

check this topic. it should cover all your needs in rounded corners:
[Emulating CSS3 border-radius and box-shadow in IE7/8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687804/emulating-css3-border-radius-and-box-shadow-in-ie7-8)

Answer (score 0):

```
border-top-left-radius:3px;
border-top-right-radius:3px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:3px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:3px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:3px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:3px;
```

This will work in Mozilla and Webkit browsers and anything supporting CSS3 border-radius property.  IE = no go.  Also, you should note that FF2 will support this but the rounded edge is not very pretty.