# CSS3Pie causing startup error

Tags: javascript, css3pie

When importing CSS3Pie, I'm getting the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'attachEvent'
```

I am using Chrome. Is this possibly something I have caused, or just a bug. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you be using CSS3Pie in Chrome?

Comment: @ken Using Head.JS

@pointy Because Chrome isn't the only browser that will see this page

Comment: ???  PIE is only useful in Internet Explorer.

Comment: @pointy Yes, but I still need to import it, unless I want to make every single rounded corners call in javascript inside a conditional script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you should be importing the "PIE.js" file in an IE-only conditional comment:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src='PIE.js'></script>
<![endif]-->
```

The CSS3Pie project is an **Internet Explorer** facility - it **only** works on IE, and is completely useless for all other browsers.

*edit* — note that this is if you're importing the stuff as a .js file in the first place. As far as I can tell, the CSS3Pie docs all encourage the functionality to be imported via the IE "behavior" CSS attribute. That attribute will just be ignored by Chrome and Firefox and Safari and everything else that's not IE.

Comment: Yup. I've never used it except via behavior. Works fine where needed, ignored where not.