# IE8 solution for rounding the corners of slideshow images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, jcycle

I have a simple **jCycle** slideshow. I want to automatically round the corners of the images so I won't have to manually round each one of the images. In the past I've used **CSS3pie** to round objects for IE, but if I use it for images within a slideshow it makes the slideshow disappear in IE8. I have no idea why (I tried following the advice on the pie site for the known issues, but to no avail). Everything works great in the other browsers...

Other solutions I've tried that have failed:

[IE-CSS3 Behaviour](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/)

[Curved Corner Behaviour](http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner)

[DDRoundies](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/)

[jQuery Corner](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/)

[cornerz jQuery Script](https://github.com/weepy/cornerz)

**HTML**:

```
<div class="slideshow">
        <img src="images/one.jpg" width="480" height="311" /> 
        <img src="images/two.jpg" width="480" height="311" /> 
 </div
```

**CSS**:

```
.slideshow  {   
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Could you please direct me to some other potential solutions or what has worked for you? I'm starting to lose patient with IE. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687804/emulating-css3-border-radius-and-box-shadow-in-ie7-8/2715717#2715717

Answer (score 3):

I think for ie you should either use Sliding Windows Technique. The CSS3 implementations wont work. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe I'm wrong here, but I don't see how I can use the Sliding Technique with images.