# drop shadow on HTML objects

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropshadow

I am trying to get a dropshadow effect going on selected HTML elements (input text, select, div etc).

The solutions given by many internet users were using CSS3 solution where it uses:

```
-moz-box-shadow
-webkit-box-shadow
box-shadow
```

However, this will not work on IE8 (possibly other IE versions)

Is there any way of creating this effect without using these CSS3 elements?

Comment: [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

Comment: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/06/14/kogan_ie7_tax/ follow suit?

Comment: [**Random Google Result**](http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/16/drop-shadow-with-css-for-all-web-browsers/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emulating CSS3 border-radius and box-shadow in IE7/8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687804/emulating-css3-border-radius-and-box-shadow-in-ie7-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure how it can be done without CSS3 but what I know is

```
.shadow { 
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000; 
box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000; 
/* For IE 8 */ 
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')"; 
/* For IE 5.5 - 7 */ 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000'); 
}
```

will work in all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

use this css for ie-8

```
.shadow
{
width:300px;
height:200px;
background-color:red;

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#000000', Direction=145, Strength=3)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use [CSS3 pie](http://css3pie.com/) for a ridiculously cross-browser solution.