# CSS Border and Shadow Issue on IE8/IE9

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Emulating CSS3 border-radius and box-shadow in IE7/8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687804/emulating-css3-border-radius-and-box-shadow-in-ie7-8)

I can't fix this problem. It's CSS `box-shadows` and round (`border-radius`) issue. My website link address http://www.shibbir.byethost7.com/.

In `Firefox`, `Chrome`, `Opera` browser it's show my website content shadow and rounded corner (Footer part.)

BUT In `Internet Explorer` It's doesn't show the shadow and rounded corner.

**Can you please help me about this?**

Comment: Next time please write which version IE You talking about.

Answer (score 2):

You won't get rounded corners in IE8, and you need to use a filter for the box shadow for IE8 as well.

Something like this:

```
filter: 
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#aaaaaa,direction=135,strength=10);
```

Comment: How do i do this for shadow and corner

Comment: Where should i put this code. inside .footer(class)

Comment: You actually spelled it `.fotter` but yea just add the block of code I provided to your class below the `box-shadow` rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use modernizer paired with polyfills to create the effects in IE, here is a list of polyfills:
https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills