# Browser compatibility issues with CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I designed a few web pages using some CSS3. It looks good in Google Chrome, but the styles become clumsy in Internet Explorer. I have two questions regarding these:

---

Can I do something like this : I can make two style sheets and depending the browser of the user load the appropriate version. Let me make it more clear:

```
if browser is Internet Explorer
    use stylesheet1.css
else
    use stylesheet2.css
```

---

My main problem is with the usage of `border-radius` property. Is there some way to avoid this directly.

Comment: what version of IE are we talking about?

Comment: if you're not sure, open IE, press CTRL+H and then click 'About internet explorer'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your HTML/header do the following:

```
<!--[if IE]>
 <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "ie-css.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

You can also break it down further:

```
<!--[if IE 7 ]>     
 <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "ie7-css.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Or many other combinations:

```
<!--[if IE 7 ]>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>     <--- less than IE7
<!--[if gt IE 7]>     <--- greater than IE7
<!--[if IE 8 ]>
<!--[if IE 9 ]>
<!--[if !IE]>
```

The recommendation (and conditionals used) by [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/):

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: What about the other style sheet. How do I use it ??

Comment: Got it posted a second before I did. Good call. +1

Comment: just add the css that work for chrome and FF like you normally do, and the code from @nickhar will be included only IF the user is using IE

Comment: Thanks.. But I meant about other browsers like Chrome, Mozilla, Safari etc Where do I put their style sheets. What would be their conditions ??

Comment: You don't need to have conditions for other browser's.  Have a base stylesheet that is included for all browsers, and IE overrides for only IE.

Answer (score 2):

[Yes, you can!](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) These are called conditional comments, and do exactly what you are looking for.

```
<link relblablabla />

<!--[if lt IE9]>
    <link relblablabla />
<![endif]-->
```

The above example will load the alternative, second stylesheet if, and only if, the Internet Explorer version you are using is less than IE9. Check out the link above for more examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix these kinds of things by having 2 different css files.
read his solution on the whole cross-browsing issue:

[Emulating CSS3 border-radius and box-shadow in IE7/8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687804/emulating-css3-border-radius-and-box-shadow-in-ie7-8)

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

call a function in onload

```
function something()
{
nav=navigator.userAgent;
if (nav.indexOf("IE 8.0")!=-1)
{    

    var $ = document; 
    var cssId = 'myCss';  // you could encode the css path itself to generate id..
    if (!$.getElementById(cssId))
    {
        var head  = $.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var link  = $.createElement('link');
        link.id   = cssId;
        link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
        link.type = 'text/css';
        link.href = 'css/cssyouwant.css';
        link.media = 'all';
        head.appendChild(link);
    }
}
}
```

navigtor.userAgent shows your browser name.