# Exclude Older IE for Media Queries

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries

I'm designing a responsive site using CSS media queries, which I understand are not supported in IE8 and below. I have devised what I think is a good method for only using css queries for IE9 and all other browsers, but I wanted to float it by you all to see if I'm missing anything or if there are holes in my plan. My method is:

1. Call my main style.css file, which all browsers will use.
2. Call a css file with my media queries for all browsers except IE with:

   ```
   [if !IE]
   import media queries stylesheet here
   [endif]
   ```
3. Call the media queries stylesheet for IE9 with:

   ```
   [if IE 9]
   import media queries stylesheet here
   [endif]
   ```

Does anyone see problems with such a plan? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plan is sound, but it needs tweaking as you make no reference to *future versions* of IE and thus you may potentially exclude a lot future visitors/users.

Given the plethora of communities/businesses (read: *half the world*) that use IE, it's best to use a slightly modified version of what you've already proposed:

```
<!--[if !IE]> 
   @media queries for all browsers except IE
<![endif]-->
```

And more importantly:

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]> //greater than IE 8
   @media queries for IE9 and above
<![endif]-->
```

Both these statements in combination exclude all versions of IE prior to version 9, but more importantly **include future versions**.

A [prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585333/browser-compatibility-issues-with-css3/13585432#13585432) demonstrates other possibilities with regard to versions and some of the different permutations and combinations you can use.