# How to add border-radius in IE7/8

Tags: css, css3pie

I need help about css.I want round corners in IE. I tried lots of things, included:

```
behavior:url(border-radius.htc);
```

or

```
behavior:url(PIE.htc);
```

or

```
behavior:url(PIE.php);
```

But it does not work. I don know how to do and I don even wanna do it with background image.

Comment: For old browsers, highly recommend you to use image instead.

Comment: The best way to do this is to use modernizr and see if border-radius is supported. When it's not use an image instead

Comment: I found that css3pie slowed things down too much in iE7, which is one of the browsers I really needed it for. For rounded corners, I just take a "graceful degradation" approach, as they are not typically a feature that the UX really hinges.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 pie should work.  I would check that your paths are correct.  Unfortunately anything earlier than IE9 does not have native for rounded corners

You have a few other options

- Use a background image or corner images for each corner
- Use a jQuery plugin like [this one](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/)

Finally I wish you good luck

Answer (score 0):

An option, as  mentioned, is CSS3 PIE, which work around this problem for you and implement border-radius in older versions of IE. I'm using this in a couple of projects and it works very well.

check for more details

[Emulating CSS3 border-radius and box-shadow in IE7/8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687804/emulating-css3-border-radius-and-box-shadow-in-ie7-8)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Look, I write so `.form{
behavior:url(PIE.htc);
border-radius: 30px;
` and it does not work. Is something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

For your question it is clear that you're using `CSS3PIE`.

> The problem is that you're not importing it properly.

**From my previous answer:**

I too faced the same issue and following was the reason for my problem:

- I used a wrong positioning for my `DIV` element.
- I was targeting the wrong path in `behavior`.

From your code, the problem seems to be in targeting the wrong path.
`behavior: url(/owmw/web/css/PIE.htc);`

**FIX:**
 Instead try to refer the PIE.htc file in css folder and make it look like `behavior: url(PIE.htc);`
or
use `behavior: url(owmw/web/css/PIE.htc);`

Check out [behavior property](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/behavior).

I might be wrong, but this solved my issue.

Comment: @name where you have your `PIE.htc` file?

Comment: Thanks for answer, but my path is right. And what should be my DIV positioning?  tried to give div absolute and relative positions.

Comment: PIE.htc is in the roof. I use wordpress, it is in the folder themes/twentytwelve. My style.css is also there.

Comment: @name you should give the full path in the URL.  for eg: `behavior: url(themes/twentytwelve/PIE.htc);`.

Comment: @name ok.  Lets try once again.  Give me the directory path that or your file organisation.

Comment: ok, look.. I put my PIE.htc in twentytwelve folder. And my style.css is also there.

Comment: @name no your file organisation.  I think you have not tried css3PIE so far.  First try local like create a folder with that put your html file (try border-radius and behavior:url(PIE.htc);)and PIE.htc in it. Once you get this working, you can fix it there :) Hope you got some idea.

Comment: hmm... how I have not tried. Now I downloaded it, Put in the same directory and wrote `behaviour:url(PIE/PIE.htc)`. Wrong?

Comment: @name: you're right.  only PIE.htc is enough too.  **FYI:**This is how I tried **foldername: Checkins**  within that sample.html and PIE.htc  then `behaviour:url(PIE.htc)`.